# String index out of range on otherwise fine code (dictionary of tweets) - python

Tags: python, text, twitter

I'm super desperate.

I imported a long list of tweets that looks like this for each line:

```
[29.5912325, -98.370464330000004]       6      2011-08-28 19:02:31     @AyLaTayLa let me guess wing stop lol"
```

Each section in the tweet is separated by a tab (\t). 
Printing (d) and printing (x) works but the moment that I attempt to return dictlist, there's a string out of range error originating at line:

```
 if line[0] == '[':
```

I've tried indenting at different points but I either get another error or dictlist just returns the first tweet. Help!

```
from datetime import datetime
dictlist = []

def make_tweets(): 
    file_name = open('/users/s/Desktop/project/all_tweets.txt', 'r') 
    file_name = file_name.readlines() 
    file_name = [x.strip() for x in file_name] 
    for line in file_name: 
        if line[0] == '[': 
            d ={} 
            x = line.split("\t") 
            x[0] = x[0].split(" ")
            x[0][0] = float(x[0][0].strip(",""[")) 
            x[0][1] = float(x[0][1].strip("]"))
            x[2] = datetime.strptime('2011-08-28 19:02:28', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
            x[3] = x[3].lower() 
            #print(x)
            d['latitude'] = x[0][0] 
            d['longitude'] = x[0][1]
            d['time'] = x[2] 
            d['text'] = x[3]

            dictlist.append(dict(d))   
            #printing d works but anything beyond that
    return dictlist
```

make_tweets()

When I print d, dictionaries look like this:

```
{'latitude': 39.99230957, 'longitude': -75.13111973, 'time': datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 28, 19, 2, 28), 'text': '@_tweetthis what dorm r you in?'}
{'latitude': 54.10410612, 'longitude': 28.33601993, 'time': datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 28, 19, 2, 28), 'text': '@andykozik круто !!!'}
{'latitude': 19.47690987, 'longitude': -71.34471434, 'time': datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 28, 19, 2, 28), 'text': '@ninosh_flow jajajaj mi hermanasoooo'}
```

[SEE FOR ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEHNI.png)

Comment: Did you mean to not indent return dictlist?

Comment: Sorry it was the formatting of the question. I fixed what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Pause for a moment and ponder what's actually going wrong here. You seem to have a rather voodoo approach to indentation from the way you describe things.

I'm obviously guessing here since I have no data to check it myself, but I suspect you're running into an empty line at some point.

It, being empty, does not have a first element, and thus throws an IndexError presumably. If it's something else, well, goes to show why you should include the errors too.

Comment: Just checked - no empty lines.

Comment: How did you verify that, print(line)?

Comment: if line[0] == '':, print(line + 'found')

Comment: That condition is never going to come to pass if the line is actually empty. You're currently printing strings of length 1 or more that contain a quotation mark, i.e. ' " ' (spaces added for legibility).

Comment: So how would I find an empty line? Although I'm 80% sure that's not the issue

Comment: if not line: print('Empty line found!'), for example. More than one way to do it though.